# Relevance in broker queries

Tags: broker, search

Is there any way to obtain the results of a Broker Query with something similar to a relevance value?

I'm doing a query of components with 3 categories, and the query may be a combination of 3 keywords, but if I use a **KeywordCriteria** with **AND**, only components with the 3 matching keywords will be obtained. And if I use an **OR** operator, then components with one, two or three keyword will match, but in this case, is there any way to sort the results by relevance, hence the first results will match 3 keywords, then the following results match 2 keywords and so on?

Comment: Be sure to also try with `CustomMetaValueCriteria` and not just matching keywords and/or values. As an example, this specifically looks for "city = San Diego": `value = new CustomMetaValueCriteria(new CustomMetaKeyCriteria("city"), "San Diego");`. You can get unexpected results if just checking keywords. :-) I described [this in a blog post](http://www.createandbreak.net/2011/08/new-tridion-2011-criteria-objects.html).

Answer (score 5):

I suspect that, even if it is possible to formulate a query using the Broker API, then this may be difficult to write, maintain and not very scalable.

Have you considered getting all of the Components using the `OR` statement and doing some server-side (.NET or JAVA) processing to determine the 'relevance'?
*(I have seen something similar done with an addition XML DCP to work with server-side.  Although this would be additional templating and work for the Publisher.)*

This would probably also make it easier for future changes.  For example, if the Categories needed to have a ranking between them  (e.g.  Components tagged with Category 1 are more important than those tagged with Category 2 AND Category 3) or if certain Keywords were more important.

Comment: I think that about sums it up. You could do it, but not using native broker features. I'd suggest making a feature request on the ideas site though.

Comment: Thanks @Dominic.  +1 for the shout out to the [Tridion Ideas site](http://ideas.sdltridion.com/)

Answer (score 2):

As Jonathan Williams has already alluded to, it isn't possible to do this directly using the Broker API - you would have to run multiple queries and process the results in code.  However, I thought I would share a couple of ideas for achieving this, assuming you don't mind bypassing the API and getting straight into the SQL.  (I was going to blog about this in more detail, but as I never have time, this is as good a place as any!  Note that the code is based on SQL Server.)

For our examples, let's pretend we have two metadata fields, Fruit_Colour and Fruit_Type.

So, starting with a very basic case where we simply want to say, if Component X has more metadata values (by count) than Component Y, bring back the Components in ranked order.  We could do this with the following simple SQL statement:

```
SELECT ITEM_ID, PUBLICATION_ID, KEY_NAME,
COUNT(KEY_STRING_VALUE) OVER (PARTITION BY ITEM_ID) AS 'COUNT'
FROM CUSTOM_META
WHERE KEY_STRING_VALUE IN ('Yellow', 'Citrus')
AND ITEM_TYPE = 16
ORDER BY COUNT DESC
```

The end result is a ranked list of Components, with those having both values being highest in the list.  (One could also add `TOP()` and additional `WHERE` clauses to narrow down the list).

Now let's extend the example a little.  How about we want to say that being a certain colour is more important that being of a certain type (for example, through user input filters).  We can achieve this by using the SQL Server `RANK()` function and a little SQL-fu!  In the following code sample, I'm going to use a TABLE variable that will substitute for our user input:

```
-- Declare table variable for our example
DECLARE @weights TABLE (value NVARCHAR(50), weight INT);    

-- Insert values into table variable for example
INSERT INTO @weights VALUES ('Yellow', 75);
INSERT INTO @weights VALUES ('Citrus', 25);    

-- Create an aliased result set, ranking the rows by weight while joining over the metadata value (KEY_STRING_VALUE)
WITH ranked_content AS (
SELECT ITEM_ID, PUBLICATION_ID, KEY_NAME, KEY_STRING_VALUE, 
  RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY weight ORDER BY ITEM_ID) AS 'RANKING'
FROM CUSTOM_META
LEFT JOIN @weights ON KEY_STRING_VALUE = value
WHERE ITEM_TYPE = 16
)    

-- Select what we want from the result set above and order by ranking
SELECT DISTINCT(ITEM_ID), PUBLICATION_ID, MAX(RANKING) AS 'RANKING'
FROM ranked_content
GROUP BY ITEM_ID, PUBLICATION_ID
ORDER BY RANKING DESC
```

This will return a ranked list of Components based on the values and associated weights input.

There are lots ways to do this, depending on your needs (for example, you could change the second example to use `KEY_NAME` so that you could rank by the presence and weight of a given key, rather than the value), but my intention is to give you some ways to get started.  Enjoy!

Comment: Thanks for the mention Tristan.  I have worked on implementations that queried the Broker database directly (mainly to get around limitations in the R5.2 API) in the past.  It is worth noting that this is not a supported solution.  As well as the code not being unsupported, I wouldn't be surprised if direct database access (even just for reads) invalidates support on the infrastructure/performance side too.  There is also a risk that any upgrades/hotfixes (that change the database structure) may break the code.  That said, this is probably the best solution from a performance standpoint.